# Openlayers + PaperJS - Is it possible?

Tags: openlayers-3, paperjs

I'd like to increase some animation on Openlayers maps. I've tried D3, but D3 is specially SVG. I've tried D3 and Leaflet and had some result, but I really prefer ol3.

So, I've made some tests with PaperJS, but I guess I have some scope issues. [This is what I've got so far](http://embed.plnkr.co/SlmmovXu5dzFMAmtJtbt/preview).

As you can see the onFrame listener never reaches. So I need to broadcast the animation listener through the [canvasFunction](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.source.ImageCanvas.html?unstable=true), but I don't know how.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Forgot to mention: this guy made an [impressive integration](http://darrenwiens.net/paperjs_directions.html) (ok, not so impressive and not so integrated) between Google Maps API and PaperJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer to my own question is:

When working with PaperJS and javascript directly you gotta attach the onFrame to the view object.

So the [plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/SlmmovXu5dzFMAmtJtbt/) is updated (it is buggy but it is a start).

Answer (score 0):

If the animations you need are not so complex, I would suggest to rely on the OpenLayers API to create feature animations. The basic idea is to create some controls that draw the feature as you mouse moves.

Also there are API to control [animations for maps](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/examples/animation.html).

The map of the given example (google map + PaperJS) does not have any map interactions. I think some more work will be needed to make it work smoothly with map interactions (zoom in/out, pan, turn layer on/off, etc).

Comment: thanks, but I do need a 3rd party "help" and if you look carefully there's a lot of interactions between GMaps and Paper ... [link](https://darrenwiens.wordpress.com/tag/paperjs/page/2/)

Comment: By interaction, I mean the interaction between the user and the map. For example, in google map, scroll mouse for map zooming, drag mouse for map panning.  If you check out the js code, it get the route from google map direction service, but draw it on canvas instead of on the map, and so as the animation (it transform the lonlat into screen pixels, and the map and canvas are even in different dom elements). Hence, the map have no control on the routes. When zooming/panning the map, the canvas animation will remain the same.

Comment: But of course if what you want is just a map without user interaction, then we have no problem.

Comment: sorry, didn't notice the new link ;)  Create buttons to bind canvas and map seems to be a good option although I guess it require some effort to implement complex interaction.

Comment: OL3 has a "bridge" to external canvas like this example [link](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/d3.html)

Comment: thanks for your attention - you're right, it is not a really interaction.